# fill-in absent rows in data.frame

Tags: r

I have two `data.frame`s, `df` and `wf`.

`df` has a one row per time point for each `id`. Some time points (`tpoint`) are missing for each `id`.

My second `data.frame`, `wf`, has the appropriate beginning and end `tpoint`s for each `id` i.e. `spoint` and `epoint` respectively.

So I want to fill in missing rows in `df` for the missing `tpoints`.  Below are the `data.frames`

```
df <- read.table(text= "id Gid tpoint dat1 dat2 dat3
                     1   a    1     x     x  55
                     1   a    3     x     x  44
                     1   a    4     x     x  33
                     2   a    2     x     x  66
                     2   a    3     x     x  43
                     3   b    4     x     x  42
                     3   b    5     x     x  36
                     4   b    4     x     x  33
                     4   b    5     x     x  65
                     4   b    6     x     x  77
                     5   b    4     x     x  72
                     5   b    5     x     x  25
                     5   b    6     x     x  12
                     5   b    7     x     x  09",header=TRUE)

 wf <- read.table(text= "id Gid spoint epoint
                     1   a    1     5
                     2   a    1     4
                     3   b    4     6
                     4   b    4     7
                     5   b    4     7",header=TRUE)
```

I figured out a way to do this below:

```
library(plyr)

seqlist  <- apply(wf, 1, function(x) data.frame( id=x[1], 
                                                 Gid=x[2],
                                                 tpoint = seq(x[3], x[4])))
# bunch of warnings but I get the result

seqdf    <- ldply(seqlist, data.frame)
finaldf  <- merge(seqdf, df, by=c("Gid", "id", "tpoint"), all=TRUE)
```

I get a bunch of ugly warnings although I get where I want to be. But I guess *all warnings should be suppressed*. There are infinite ways to skin a cat in `R`. Is there a much better way to be doing this I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors occur because:

1. In the call to `apply()` the data frame gets coerced to an array, in this case a character array)
2. This means each row is now a named character vector
3. When coercing the named vector to a data frame, R lets you know that it is discarding all the names.

To remove the warnings, try this:

```
seqlist  <- apply(wf, 1, function(x){
  n <- as.numeric(x[4])-as.numeric(x[3])+1
  data.frame( id=rep(x[1], n), Gid=rep(x[2], n), tpoint = x[3]:x[4])
})

seqlist
[[1]]
  id Gid tpoint
1  1   a      1
2  1   a      2
3  1   a      3
4  1   a      4
5  1   a      5

[[2]]
  id Gid tpoint
1  2   a      1
2  2   a      2
3  2   a      3
4  2   a      4

[[3]]
  id Gid tpoint
1  3   b      4
2  3   b      5
3  3   b      6

[[4]]
  id Gid tpoint
1  4   b      4
2  4   b      5
3  4   b      6
4  4   b      7

[[5]]
  id Gid tpoint
1  5   b      4
2  5   b      5
3  5   b      6
4  5   b      7
```